# iPad orientation notifications lost when transition for keyWindow

Tags: ipad, uiview, transition

I have an animation done over the keyWindow of the app.

```
[UIView beginAnimations:kAnimationLogin context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:window_ cache:NO];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];

[window_ addSubview:splitViewController_.view];

[UIView commitAnimations]; 

[loginViewController_.view removeFromSuperview];
```

This works ok. Then, if the user logouts, the transition is the reverse

```
[UIView beginAnimations:kAnimationLogout context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:window_ cache:NO];    
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];

[window_ addSubview:loginViewController_.view];

[UIView commitAnimations];

[splitViewController_.view removeFromSuperview];
```

Here is the problem. Now, loginViewController_ and splitViewController_ don't receive the orientation notifications. Why?

Comment: Do you mean they don't receive the orientation change notifications after the animations. Do they receive them if the animations are not performed?

Comment: yes, techZen, that's the point, if I don't do the transition the orientation issue doesn't appear but if I do it the problem begins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's not a great solution but I've found a way to avoid that problem. First of all, I think that the problem comes because, while animation, both view controllers receives the orientation notifications while, I guess, adding and removing to and from the window and raises the problem. I don't know exactly if it's an issue related to view hierarchy (I guess it's correct but I'm not sure) or not.

So, the solution I use is to put the LoginViewController as a ModalViewController of SplitViewController, that is the main controller, and use a FlipHorizontal transition while showing.

That solves the problem.